# is fb:profile-pic works in new graph api(iframe) application?

Tags: php, facebook, fbml, xfbml

Hi i m creating iframe application in facebook using new graph api. I want to display user's friends profile pics in page. so i use following code in loop

```
echo "
<fb:profile-pic uid="id" size="normal" linked="false"></fb:profile-pic>";
```

here id is user's friends id that change in loop.

This code works fine but my question is that: Is it right to use fbml tag fb:profile-pic in iframe app.? Please help me to understand this.

Thank you.

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
<img src='http://graph.facebook.com/FACEBOOK_ID/picture' />
```

Edit:
as others mentioned, FBML is being deprecated by facebook.

Answer (score 0):

These FBML tags are slowly being deprecated by facebook. You can use the graph api instead.
In order to access the profile picture in the graph api, you need to access:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/ID/picture
```

Using the php SDK this would be fb->api('/ID/picture')

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is deprecating FBML, so please dont use it to develop applications. you can use php with the graph api to create iframe applications.